# Symfony 4 how to enable prod mode?

Tags: symfony

In Symfony 4, the *index.php* sets dev mode by default

```php
$env = $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev';
```

Symfony official doc says : Symfony Dotenv should only be used in ***development/testing/staging*** environments. For production environments, use "real" environment variables.

So I understand : `APP_ENV=prod` as environment variable is mandatory to enable prod mode.

Am I right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to ensure that the environment variable `APP_ENV` is set correctly in your production environment. The documentation tells you how to do this for [various web servers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html). For example, in your Apache-configuration you have to use `SetEnv`. This could look something like this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
<Directory /var/www/project/public>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

SetEnv APP_ENV prod
SetEnv APP_DEBUG 0
...
```

A similar configuration for nginx would use `fastcgi_param` and would look somewhat like this:

```
location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
    fastcgi_param APP_DEBUG 0;
}
```

The doc page is a bit mean, because the respective bits are commented out.

If you want to simulate the production environment with the built-in webserver you can do it like this:

```
APP_ENV=prod APP_DEBUG=0 bin/console server:run
```

This requires the server-pack to be installed using composer and of course you can also set the command option `--env` as well, for the same effect.

And also make sure that you have checked `.env` and `.env.local` file too.

```
# prod config of .env or/and .env.local
APP_ENV=prod
APP_DEBUG=0
```

Comment: thxs @dbrumann the configuration web server doc was the missing page. So without custom dev, APP_ENV is mandatory