# Symfony 4 debug production environments

Tags: symfony, debugging, symfony4

how to debug Symfony 4 project on production environment? I mean in a way that only I from particular IP can do it. In Symfony 2/3 I have app_dev.php controller. How to do this with Symfony 4 and Apache?
If I change  in .env or via VirtualHost APP_ENV to dev then all app users will see debug toolbar, exception logs etc.

Comment: what stops you to add and test what changes after some lines of code in  `public/index.php`  for hardcode setting up `$_SERVER['APP_ENV']`,  `$_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']` and `$_ENV['APP_DEBUG']` like in config/bootstrap.php ?

Comment: If I add it to index.php all users will use the app in DEV environtment instead of PROD. If I addd it as a IP depdendant, I will alywas see the app in DEV mode. The idea is to use DEV when I want without a need to change anything in the code.

Comment: ) ofcause with specifying ip for allow DEV only for specific `IP`, not for all ) 
without changing anything in the code - impossible!  you must change in your  apache *.conf  on index.php
or start another  input script, that  will  loads as index.php but with your  preinstalled config(maybe with login/password, only by 1 IP)

Answer (score 2):

You can copy/paste `index.php` for `dev.php` and change :

```
//$env = $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev';
$env = 'dev';
```

> http://yourwebsite.com/dev.php/

You can restrict for you IP or delete after your actions.

Comment: Well, that would be the best option for me. I wonder why Symfony authors decided not to use it.

Comment: Debug isn't safe in production :) You have logs (`/var/logs`) for that :)

Comment: Yes, but Prod logs doesn't have so much data as Dev logs. And this doesn't give a possibility to check Profiler for debug. For me app_dev was a good solution. So probably I will do it as you wrote, copy pase and restrict. I just don't get it why it was OK with Symfony 2 and 3 and it is not for 4.

Comment: Monolog is very useful in these situations. You can create an event listener for exceptions and create highly specified messages for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Symfony environment configured by system environment variables. So just add in apache app config (.htaccess by default) something like 

`SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127.0.0.1" APP_ENV=dev APP_DEBUG=1`

(needs https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_setenvif.html)

Comment: Yes, but this way I will always have debug env while on my IP. Many time I had a problem that existed in Prod env but not on dev. As @Gaylord.P wrote I can have both app and app_dev and use it when I want. I just don't get it why it was OK with Symfony 2 and 3 and it is not for 4

Comment: based on enabling env in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48869783/5809937   this solution is better

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using the profiler in a production environment although with Apache you could "emulate" Symfony 2 - 3 behaviour if you configure like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
DocumentRoot "/yourRootDirectory"

<Directory "/yourRootDirectory/">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Require all granted
</Directory>       

...

SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/app_dev.php APP_ENV=dev           

Alias /app_dev.php "/yourRootDirectory/"
<Location "/app_dev.php">        
    Require local
</Location>
...        
</VirtualHost>
```

Requesting `http://localhost/app_dev.php` from localhost machine you get your app in Symfony 4, 5 in dev mode with profiler like in Symfony 2, 3.

Special attention to `Require local` for your alias, also you could to use `Require ip 192.168.1.1 127.0.0.1` or the IPs you want (see Apache docs). But be careful to expose the dev environment to an ip or computer that is not under your control.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit of a broad question.

The best way is to use a logging tool like monolog, default output directory is `project/var/log/env.log`.

As why you are seeing `all app users will see debug toolbar, exception logs etc.` has to do with your environment settings.

Symfony 4 environment settings work as follows, load `config/packages/(env)/package.yaml` then load default/production configurations `config/packages/package.yaml`(if exists). 
When you set your env dev you are loading `config/packages/dev/web_profiler.yaml` and in production, there is no definition for that plugin which defaults to not showing up.

Here is more information about environment setup in symfony 4 .https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html